# Amazon EC2 and Pen-Testing Form

Tags: amazon-ec2, penetration-testing

I want to get an Amazon EC2 instance (first year trial is for free) for my tutorials but I have found out that I need to complete form about Pen-Testing on their website, as I will be using Amazon EC2 instance only to perform such actions on my own systems which I physically own so I was just wondering if a normal person like me can apply for it or is it just limited to a companies and normal users can't apply for it ?

I will appreciate any help.

Kind Regards

Comment: AWS can terminate any account for violating their service term.  pen-testing without informing are one of those (and pending on AWS approval).  Pen-testing will enact some behavior and traffics that might alarm AWS admin as malicious behavior and threat to the grid. You are definitely not the first one trying this stunt.

Comment: what 'stunt' is he trying? He is requesting information about filling out the pen-testing authorization form? There is a process for this and it sounds he s/he is following it.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply just like anybody else - no special qualifications needed. Mostly they want to make sure you are only pen testing against your own instances, not somebody else's instance.

But also keep in mind, since it sounds like you are trying to stay within the free-tier, that you are probably going to need to pay for a bigger instance to test against:

***At this time, our policy does not permit testing small or micro RDS instance types. Testing of m1.small or t1.micro EC2 instance types is not permitted. This is to prevent potential adverse performance impacts on resources that may be shared with other customers.***

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that I can't perform such testing on a free tier ? I thought I could do it since it's a free trial... I must say, I'm a bit disappointed, how expensive is to rent the another instance of Amazon EC2 for such purpose ?

Comment: You could do 100 hours of pen testing on a medium instance for approx $5.